# How to remove edit TKinter widget Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im trying to set up simple frame work for a trashy hang man game, the images are named in series of 6 for each stage of failure. S0 is the beginning and S6, is the final stage.

Im trying to figure out how to upudate the photo.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
i=0

frameLeft = Frame(root)
frameRight = Frame(root)
frameRight.pack(side=RIGHT)
frameLeft.pack(side=LEFT)

#frame Left

#function Declaration
entry1 = Entry(frameLeft)
entry1.pack()
def updatePhoto():
        i = entry1.get()
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("S" + i + ".gif"))
        imgPanel = Label(frameRight, image = img)
        imgPanel.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
labelInstruction = Label(frameLeft, text=entry1.get())
labelInstruction.pack()
submitButton = Button(frameLeft, text="Submit", command=updatePhoto)
submitButton.pack()

#frame Right

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("S" + str(i) + ".gif"))
imgPanel = Label(frameRight, image = img)
imgPanel.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of these lines:

```
imgPanel = Label(frameRight, image = img)
imgPanel.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

I was able to use these

```
imgPanel.configure(image=img)
imgPanel.image = img
```

I also changed the order of left and right side making right come first as it's a scripting language and requires declaration.